# Prevent CTRL+C being sent to process called from a Bash script

Tags: bash, wait, exit, keyboard-events, sigint

Here is a simplified version of some code I am working on:

```
#!/bin/bash

term() {
  echo ctrl c pressed!
  # perform cleanup - don't exit immediately
}
trap term SIGINT

sleep 100 &
wait $!
```

As you can see, I would like to trap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / `SIGINT` and handle these with a custom function to perform some cleanup operation, rather than exiting immediately.

However, upon pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, what actually seems to happen is that, while I see `ctrl c pressed!` is echoed as expected, the `wait` command is also killed which I would not like to happen (part of my cleanup operation kills `sleep` a bit later but first does some other things). Is there a way I can prevent this, i.e. stop <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> input being sent to the `wait` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a modified version of what @thatotherguy suggested:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

term() {
  echo ctrl c pressed!
  # perform cleanup - don't exit immediately
}
trap term SIGINT

sleep 100 &
pid=$!

while ps -p $pid > /dev/null; do
  wait $pid
done
```

This checks if the process is still running and, if so, runs `wait` again.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent a process called from a Bash script from receiving sigint by first ignoring the signal with `trap`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Cannot be interrupted
( trap '' INT; exec sleep 10; )
```

However, only a parent process can wait for its child, so `wait` is a shell builtin and not a new process. This therefore doesn't apply.

Instead, just restart the `wait` after it gets interrupted:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
term() {
  echo "ctrl c pressed!"
  n=$((n+1))
}
trap term INT


sleep 100 &

while
  wait "$!"
  [ "$?" -eq 130 ]   # Sigint results in exit code 128+2
do
  if [ "$n" -ge 3 ]
  then
    echo "Jeez, fine"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I just posted my own answer based on this solution :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119846/4247209